# In vbscript can you use two possible conditions in an if statement? (OR)

Tags: if-statement, vbscript, ms-word, docvariable

An example would be:

```
If filter_purchase = 0 Or "" Then
SetDocVar "filter_purchase", "0"
Else
SetDocVar "filter_purchase", CStr(filter_purchase)
End If
```

But I get a 'Type Mismatch'. Would there be an easier way than doing Else IFs?

Comment: do yo mean `filter_purchase == 0` instead of '=' ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to explicitly state the condition for each OR. Please see below

```
If filter_purchase = 0 Or filter_purchase = "" Then
   SetDocVar "filter_purchase", "0"
Else
   SetDocVar "filter_purchase", CStr(filter_purchase)
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be the condition you want

```
If ((filter_purchase = 0) Or (filter_purchase = "")) Then
```

@agamike, I believe a single = is used for comparison in a vbs if not and not == [link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h27x7e9%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to test for an uninitialized variable then your `If` expression is actually redundant. All variables in VBScript are variants and all variants start out with a default value of `0/False/""`. For example:

```
Dim v
If v = ""    Then MsgBox "Empty string"
If v = 0     Then MsgBox "Zero"
If v = False Then MsgBox "False"
```

All three of these tests will pass. Note how you can compare a single variable against string, numeric, and boolean literals. Uninitialized variables have no type yet, so these kinds of comparisons are completely fine.

However, once you *assign* a value to the variable, you need to consider its type when making comparisons. For example:

```
Dim v
v = ""
If v = ""    Then MsgBox "Empty String"    ' Pass.  "" = "".
If v = 0     Then MsgBox "Zero"            ' Fail! Illegal comparison.
If v = False Then MsgBox "False"           ' Fail! "" <> False.
```

Now that the variant has been defined as holding a string, it will need to be compared against other string types (literals or variables) or values that can be cast (either implicitly or explicitly) to a string.