# VBScript error 800A0401 - Expected statement

Tags: vbscript

Why does WSH throw an error on my code saying that there is an

> "expected statement" in line 1 character 1.

Here is my code:

```vb
type = inputbox("What would you like to calculate with? (m = muliplication, d = division, a = addition, s = subtraction)")
if type = not "m" or "s" or "a" or "d" or "M" or "S" or "A" or "D" then
a=msgbox("You did not select one of the options.")
elseif type = "m" or "M" then
input1 = inputbox("You chose multiplication. What is the first number of your math sentence?")
input2 = inputbox("What is the other number of your math sentence?")
output = input1 * input2
display = msgbox("The answer to " & input1 & " " & chrw(0215) & " " & input2 & " is " & output & ".")
elseif type = "d" or "D" then
input1 = inputbox("You chose division. What is the dividend of your math sentence?")
input2 = inputbox("What is the divisor of your math sentence?")
output = input1 \ input2
display = msgbox("The answer to " & input1 & " " & chrw(247) & " " & input2 & " is " & output & ".")
elseif type = "a" or "A" then
input1 = inputbox("You chose addition. What is the first number of your math sentence?")
input2 = inputbox("What is the other number of your math sentence?")
output = input1 + input2
display = msgbox("The answer to " & input1 & " + " & input2 & " is " & output & ".")
elseif type = "s" or "S" then
input1 = inputbox("You chose subtraction. What is the first number of your math sentence?")
input2 = inputbox("What is the other number of your math sentence?")
output = input1 - input2
display = msgbox("The answer to " & input1 & " - " & input2 & " is " & output & ".")
end if
```

I know this is kind of obvious but I don't see any error on line 1 char 1.

Please explain to me how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use the word "type" for a variable name in VBScript.

Tip: Use an editor that provides syntax highlighting, such as Notepad3, Notepad++, UltraEdit, VS Code, VBSEdit, etc. Issues like "type" being a reserved word is then instantly obvious:

[image]

Comment: Although not used in VBScript it is used by Visual Basic so that makes it a reserved word just like `As` is also a reserved word even though it’s not used in VBScript. Good answer.

Comment: Yeah that kind of works but when I run it the start inputbox works, but after that comes and error saying: Line 2 char 1 type mismatch "m". Btw I renamed all the variables in the if statements before testing.

Comment: @KhizarCaliphate The condition logic is wrong, you can't `= not`, instead try `If Not (variable = "m" Or variable = "s" Or ...)`.

Answer (score 0):

The reserved word is certainly an issue in the script as pointed out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69954055/692942), but you also have some incorrect conditional logic.

It's not valid syntax to use `Not =`  or trying to use short-circuited logic like `Or "m" Or "s"`.

Instead, restructure the `If` statement like;

```
If Not (variable = "m" Or variable = "s" Or ...) Then '... and so on using variable = "value"
```

You can also `LCase()` your result from the `InputBox()` function to avoid needing to check both upper-case and lower-case variants, like this;

```
Dim choice: choice = LCase(InputBox("What would you like to calculate with? (m = muliplication, d = division, a = addition, s = subtraction)") & "") 'Returned value will be lower-case.
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [In vbscript can you use two possible conditions in an if statement? (OR)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24223637/692942)

Answer (score 0):

@user692942 already gave the answer, the line

```
if type = not "m" or "s" or "a" or "d" or "M" or "S" or "A" or "D" then
```

is incorrect syntax.

As an alternative to multiple If/ElseIf statements, you can use Select Case/End Select:

```
Select Case LCase(Type)
    Case "a"
        input1 = inputbox("You chose addition. What is the first number of your math sentence?")
        input2 = inputbox("What is the other number of your math sentence?")
        output = input1 + input2
    Case "d"
        input1 = inputbox("You chose division. What is the dividend of your math sentence?")
        input2 = inputbox("What is the divisor of your math sentence?")
        output = input1 \ input2
        display = msgbox("The answer to " & input1 & " " & chrw(247) & " " & input2 & " is " & output & ".")
    Case "m"
        input1 = inputbox("You chose multiplication. What is the first number of your math sentence?")
        input2 = inputbox("What is the other number of your math sentence?")
        output = input1 * input2
        display = msgbox("The answer to " & input1 & " " & chrw(0215) & " " & input2 & " is " & output & ".")
    Case "s"
        input1 = inputbox("You chose subtraction. What is the first number of your math sentence?")
        input2 = inputbox("What is the other number of your math sentence?")
        output = input1 - input2
        display = msgbox("The answer to " & input1 & " - " & input2 & " is " & output & ".")
    Case Else
        a=msgbox("You did not select one of the options.")
End Select
```

Answer (score -1):

Start over.  You cannot use "inputbox" because it runs server-side and not client-side.  Even after resolving the other issues, the script will not work.  Instead of using inputbox, create a form.

Try something like this:

```
<%
If Trim(Request.Form("strType")) = "" Then
    Response.Write  "<form action=""math.asp"" method=""post"">" & vbNewLine & _
        "   <table align=""center"" border=""1"">" & vbNewLine & _
        "       <tr>" & vbNewLine & _
        "           <td>" & vbNewLine & _
        "               <font face=""consolas"" size=""3em;"" color=""black"">What would you like to calculate with?  (m = muliplication, d = division, a = addition, s = subtraction)</font>" & vbNewLine & _
        "               <input style=""background-color:lightblue; color:navy; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;"" type=""text"" name=""strType"" value="""" size=""1"" />" & vbNewLine & _
        "           </td>" & vbNewLine & _
        "       </tr>" & vbNewLine & _
        "   </table>" & vbNewLine & _
        "</form>" & vbNewLine
    Response.End
End If
strType = LCase(Trim(Request.Form("strType")))
If strType <> "m" And strType <> "s" And strType <> "a" And strType <> "d" Then
    Response.Write  "You did not select one of the options."
    Response.End
End If
strP1 = "<input type=""hidden"" name=""strType"" value=""" & strType & """ />What is the 1st number of your math sentence?  "
strP2 = "What is the 2nd number of your math sentence?  "
strQ1 = "<input style=""background-color:lightblue; color:navy; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;"" type=""text"" name=""input1"" value="""" /><br />"
strQ2 = "<input style=""background-color:lightblue; color:navy; text-align:center; font-weight:bold;"" type=""text"" name=""input2"" value="""" /><br /></td></tr></table><center><input type=""submit"" value=""Calculate"" /></center></form>"
strE = strP1 & strQ1 & strP2 & strQ2
Response.Write  "<form action=""math.asp"" method=""post"">" & vbNewLine & _
    "   <table align=""center"" border=""1"">" & vbNewLine & _
    "       <tr>" & vbNewLine & _
    "           <td>" & vbNewLine & _
    "               <font face=""consolas"" size=""3em;"" color=""black"">" & vbNewLine
Select Case(strType)
    Case "m"
        If Trim(Request.Form("input1")) = "" Then
            Response.Write  "You chose multiplication.<br />" & strE
            Response.End
        Else
            If IsNumeric(Trim(Request.Form("input1"))) And IsNumeric(Trim(Request.Form("input2"))) Then
                Response.Write  "Answer:  " & Request.Form("input1") & " * " & Request.Form("input2") & " = " & Request.Form("input1") * Request.Form("input2")
            Else
                Response.Write  "Both values must be numeric."
                Response.End
            End If
        End If
    Case "d"
        If Trim(Request.Form("input1")) = "" Then
            Response.Write  "You chose division.<br />" & strE
            Response.End
        Else
            If IsNumeric(Trim(Request.Form("input1"))) And IsNumeric(Trim(Request.Form("input2"))) Then
                Response.Write  "Answer:  " & Request.Form("input1") & " / " & Request.Form("input2") & " = " & Request.Form("input1") / Request.Form("input2")
            Else
                Response.Write  "Both values must be numeric."
                Response.End
            End If
        End If
    Case "a"
        If Trim(Request.Form("input1")) = "" Then
            Response.Write  "You chose addition.<br />" & strE
            Response.End
        Else
            If IsNumeric(Trim(Request.Form("input1"))) And IsNumeric(Trim(Request.Form("input2"))) Then
                Response.Write  "Answer:  " & Request.Form("input1") & " + " & Request.Form("input2") & " = " & Request.Form("input1") + Request.Form("input2")
            Else
                Response.Write  "Both values must be numeric."
                Response.End
            End If
        End If
    Case Else
        If Trim(Request.Form("input1")) = "" Then
            Response.Write  "You chose subtraction.<br />" & strE
            Response.End
        Else
            If IsNumeric(Trim(Request.Form("input1"))) And IsNumeric(Trim(Request.Form("input2"))) Then
                Response.Write  "Answer:  " & Request.Form("input1") & " - " & Request.Form("input2") & " = " & Request.Form("input1") - Request.Form("input2")
            Else
                Response.Write  "Both values must be numeric."
                Response.End
            End If
        End If
End Select
%>
```

Comment: This question is only tagged "vbscript", not "asp-classic". Inputbox is fine.